# React Typescript Props Interface Containing an Interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-typescript

i have a functional component receiving props from another functional component. I have an interface on the receiving component that also contains an interface but this interface is always 'undefined' when i log in the console. However the value of the props below contains the data I was expecting to be populated into my competition interface. My component is:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ICompetition } from '../interfaces/ICompetition';

interface CompetitionProps {
   competition: ICompetition;
}

function Competition(props: CompetitionProps) {
    console.log(props);
    console.log(props.competition);
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <div id={props.competition.competitionId.toString()} className="text-left" style={{minWidth: 0, textOverflow: 'ellipsis', overflow: 'hidden'}}>                            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Competition;
```

I'm sending the data to this component using the spread operator from the component below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, } from 'react';
import "../App.css";
import { ICompetition } from '../interfaces/ICompetition';
 import Competition from './Competition';

interface HomeProps {
    bookmakerid: string | null;
}

function Home(props: HomeProps) {
    const [compList, setData] = useState<ICompetition | null>(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
     const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:5242/Competitions?bid=" + props.bookmakerid, { method: "POST" })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    return response.json();
                }
            })
            .then(data => {
                 setData(data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setError(err)
            });
    }, []);
    console.log(compList);
    return (
    <section className="section section-variant-1 bg-gray-100">
        <div className="isotope-item" data-filter="football">
            <div className="sport-table">
                <div className="sport-table-tr">

                    <div id="runnerContainer" className="carousel-inner">
                        {compList && compList instanceof Array && compList.map((comp) => (                                
                            <Competition competition={...comp} key={comp.competitionId } />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
);
}

export default Home;
```

My ICompetition interface is defined as follows

```
export interface ICompetition {
    competitionId: number;
    bookmakerId: number;
    competitionName: string;
    sportId: number;
    lastUpdated: Date;    
    venue: string;
    competitionDate: Date;
    downloadable: boolean;
    displayHead: boolean;
    headerText: string;
    competitionStatus: number;    
    sortOrder: number;
    errorCode: string;
}
```

Any help on how i could get this to work would be appreciated.

Comment: For one thing there is no property `comp.competitionId` that you can use as a key. The key is presumably `comp.competition.competitionId`

Comment: But this is based on a guess, because almost none of your problem example is in the question. For example, what is the content of compList? You need to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yep, i've just updated my question with the sending component.

Comment: comp.competition is woking from my 'Home' component

Comment: Is the `ICompetition` interface a trade secret? Why is it not shared in your example? I would strongly recommend using some online editor environment to create a minimal reproducible example with enough to create the problem (that gives everyone a chance by providing the relevant structures. You will probably fix it yourself if you invest this time before asking others, and if you can't fix it then others will be able to actually reproduce your issue using the isolated example.

Comment: I've just added my `ICompetition` interface for reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252455/discussion-between-pinman-and-cefn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  {compList && compList instanceof Array && compList.map((comp) => (                                
    <Competition competition={...comp} key={comp.competitionId } />
  ))}
```

{...comp} this code -> {comp}
and
in map function parameter add type :  comp -> comp: ICompetition
like this

```js
  {compList?.map((comp: ICompetition) => (                                
    <Competition competition={comp} key={comp.competitionId } />
  ))}
```

Then you'll be able to see if it's working well on the console as you want.

I hope this may help you.

Comment: oh... i literally just posted my answer below!

Comment: sorry jkim. it sort of looks like a stole your answer :). I'll mark your answer anyway. Thanks very much for helping.

Comment: Oh, you solved it at the same time! 
Congratulations! Let's cheer up together!

Comment: No, I didn't steal it. No! You solved it yourself!

Comment: Let's cheer up as the same developer! Happy belated New Year! Thank you for choosing my answer!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve it in the end by removing the spread operator

```
{compList && compList instanceof Array && compList.map((comp) => (                                
        <Competition competition={comp} key= {comp.competitionId } />                           
))}
```

well done me! :)

Comment: Yes, that's why I judged that `comp.competitionId` must be an invalid key, because you were spreading the comp which was inconsistent with pulling the competitionId out. They couldn't both be true but it was hard to know which was right. Because you didn't include information identifying `compList`, I couldn't help you further. People are guiding you to a minimal repro for a reason. Instead of there being 100 ambiguities that people need to guess about, there are 0.

Comment: Thanks for the input cefn. it's makes it a whole lot easier for everyone if all the details are included!